# How can I perform arithmetic on integers of arbitrary size?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

My original codes here..

```
function AddNumStrings(Str1, Str2: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
  carryStr: string;
  worker: integer;
  workerStr: string;
begin
  Result:= inttostr(length(Str1));
  Result:= '';
  carryStr:= '0';

  // make numbers the same length
  while length(Str1) < length(Str2) do Str1:= '0' + Str1;
  while length(Str1) > length(Str2) do Str2:= '0' + Str2;

  i:= 0;
  while i < length(Str1) do begin
    worker:= strtoint(copy(Str1, length(Str1) - i, 1)) + strtoint(copy(Str2, length(Str2) - i, 1)) + strtoint(carryStr);
    if worker > 9 then begin
      workerStr:= inttostr(worker);
      carryStr:= copy(workerStr, 1, 1);
      Result:= copy(workerStr, 2, 1) + Result;
    end else begin
      Result:= inttostr(worker) + Result;
      carryStr:= '0';
    end;

    inc(i);
  end; { while }
  if carryStr <> '0' then Result:= carryStr + Result;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

function yeni(s1, s2: string): string;
var
  j, i, k: integer;
  c: char;
  s: string;
begin
  k:= length(s2);
  j:= length(s1) - length(s2);
  for i:= j downto 1 do begin
    c:= s1[i];
    k:= k + 1;
    if (c <> '9') and (c <> '0') then begin
      s:= copy(s1, i, k);
      s:= AddNumStrings(s, s2);
      Setlength(s1, i - 1);
      Result:= s1 + s;
      break;
    end;

    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Button13Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i, k: integer;
    s: Ansistring;
  begin
    s:= '1111';
    for i:= 1 to 1000000 do begin
      for k:= 1 to 120 do begin
        s:= yeni(s, '4');
      end;
    end;
  end;

end.
```

Finally my string `s` has to be 1,000,000,000 length. But it takes me 68 days I think. 
How can I speed up this code?

Comment: Allocate the entire string up front, and then fill out the contents. It might help if you learnt how to indent code. It would also help if you didn't ask how to do stupid pointless tasks quickly and instead told us the real problem.

Comment: Yes ı understand what you say. I did. but my program is tooks 1 hour.ıs it good choise using Strbuilder?

Comment: David Hefferman can you contact me? I see u 15-20 times. We can chat? My English is not well.

Comment: Why don't you just ask a real question with the real problem? No string builder in d7. One call to SetLength is all you need here. One single heap alloc. But so what, this is not the real problem. What's the point in making this code quick. Quickest solution is a string literal! Answer is known at compile time.

Comment: Yes u are right. It is part of my codes. Actually, my codes are tooks 68 day for real working time? How can I solve my problem? I dont know anything. Im searching everyday it. But result is false. Delphi and programmings are hobby for me. I like them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi 7 working fast string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530665/delphi-7-working-fast-string)

Comment: Can anybody convert my codes to asm. Asm is a good choise?

Comment: You need to be able to ask the question. This one, and your previous one won't get you anywhere. Describe the real problem. In a new question. We'll help you make it a good question. The questions you've asked so far are no good.

Comment: Do not post the same question again under a different account. Instead, edit your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19530665/62576) and improve it, so we can tell what you're asking.

Comment: I have a dream. And ı learnt delphi for my dream and ı learnt Php, Html,Css. They are my hobbies. But ı cant solve this problem. This problem is last walla between ı and my dream. Ha?

Comment: Please help me, ı can pay you money. Just ı have to solve it. I dont know what can ı do? Everpeople says same thing. But ı have same problem still.

Comment: I wrote my progrem for 2 years. Everything ı learn and write my program. My teacher is google. This program takes from 2 years.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's not that difficult to tell what he's trying to do, and seriously, is all this really necessary?  If you put half the effort you've put into insulting and belittling this poster into actually trying to help him, you'd have come up with an answer by now...

Comment: @mason It's easy to answer this question. The string can be evaluated at compile time! It's just not the right question. The asker has said that the real problem is different. Ken already gave the same answer as yours, essentially when he asked the same question. He'll keep asking the same question unless we tell him to ask the **right** question.

Comment: @mason take a look at the comment to Johan's answer, and tell me I was wide of the mark. :-)

Comment: OK, that's better. Could you give us a high level view of the goal of this code?

Comment: @user2912813, can you please stop using `ı` for `I`. I in english is uppercase. It is not written using the symbol that you're using.

Comment: Ok Johan.and David Hefferman I dont say it. I said its my dream.

Comment: @Dimsak I understand you're frustrated to get this issue of yours solved. However you must understand this is a Q/A site for enthusiast and professional programmers. There's a certain way you need to ask your questions to be reasonably answerable. Not only that, but you're expected to have at least a basic understanding of what you're trying to do, and make sure that we can clearly understand what you're trying to do. We're not here to teach you how to do things, and we're also not here to write code for you, and we're certainly not here for you to recruit your own coder.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is choking on a variant of [Shlemiel The Painter's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm).  Every time you add two strings together like that, the Delphi RTL has to increase the size of the string, which possibly involves allocating a new, larger string and copying the old string over, then freeing the old string.  When you do this 10 million times, all that memory copying and reallocation is going to add up.

What you need to do to get this to run quickly is figure out up-front how long the finished string will be, then call `SetLength` on `s` and allocate your large string from the beginning. After that, keep track of the index of the highest char that hasn't been "filled in" yet. Each of your `IntToStr` calls will yield a new string; insert the `|` character and then copy the `IntToStr` results over, updating the index as you go.  That should dramatically cut down the time it takes for this code to run.

Comment: Much better will be to get rid of the calls to IntToStr which involve heap alloc. Make those calls stack based.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Interesting idea, but where are we going to find a stack-based `IntToStr`?

Comment: Well, sprintf will do nicely. I expect there's something native in the Delphi RTL in sysutils too.

Comment: FormatBuf looks like our guy

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to do arbitrary precision arithmetic using strings.
This is a bad idea.

Use a bigint library instead.
It uses arrays of integer to do the job.
A nice one is downloadable at: http://www.delphiforfun.org/Programs/Library/big_integers.htm

Or at LURD's suggestion: https://code.google.com/p/gmp-wrapper-for-delphi/

Comment: Yes ı used it but it doesnt work for me.It says limited 500.000 digis for time consideration. But my sring's length is 1.000.000.000

Comment: So remove the limitation from the code. It's much much faster than your code. I've worked with this code and know of no such limitation though.

Comment: OK, is that it? You want arbitrary precision arithmetic? Use a bigint library indeed. My advice, switch to Python, and use one of the excellent big int libraries there.

Comment: But I dont know Python.

Comment: So what? You don't know Delphi either. Or how to write a big int code. In Python you only need to learn the language and it is much easier.

Comment: Johan but when Im using this, It takes more time for me. What seconds takes for you for 123456789^123456789? I  run it but program was locked. Not responfing my laptop. And I close it from Taskmanager.

Comment: David u are right but I dont have enough time. I finished University and I m working now as Mechanical Engineering. I dont enough time. So my web site is waiting for 6 mounths. I couldnt finish it yet. Please I need it for Delphi. May be after I will learn Python.

Comment: This library will do the job, [`http://gmplib.org/`](http://gmplib.org/). A delphi wrapper can be found here, [`The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library Wrapper For Delphi`](https://code.google.com/p/gmp-wrapper-for-delphi/).

Comment: LU RD I downloaded it but I couldunt understand. How it help me?

Comment: This is why I suggest a more approachable solution. There are good big int libs for Delphi but they are hard to get into for less advanced devs.

Comment: There is a demo in the delphi wrapper download.

Comment: David Hefferman you want to see my original codes. Thare is my original codes that I wrote. Well, why dont you help me? Why did you want to see my original codes? Will anybody help me? ı m waiting here.

Comment: Yes LU RD but it is a game. What will ı do? I couldnt understand.

Comment: You've got your answer already. Use a big int lib. You've had the help that you need. Why won't you just heed the advice?

Comment: David I couldnt understand. But Bigint doesnt calculate 1.000.000.000 digit number. I couldnt understand. you say gmp lib or bigint lib. ?

Comment: @Dimsak, you are trying to do arithmetic with numbers around 1.000.000.000 digits. Doing this with strings and slow concatenation is not the correct solution. We are pointing to a solution, use this advice.

Comment: Kind of crazy you reject Python. You are not a skilled programmer, so it's too hard for you to write you own library. It's also too hard for you to install and use third party library. In Python you write x = y + z and built in have arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: LU RD yes I see and hank you so so much. But I coulndt have eny result. And big problem is my English is bad. So I couldnt understand clearly. What will I do. Can you write an exmaple?

Comment: Well, Is there any limitation Length of integer or string in Python?

Comment: Bigint test is not calculate 987654321^123456 "Not Responding" program is locked.

Comment: Your English is good. You need to slow down and ask a simple question. For example, "How can I perform arithmetic on integers of arbitrary size?"

Comment: @Dimsak Please don't be a help vampire: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem  It's bad form.

Comment: David thank you. And david I ask you: How can I perform arithmetic on integers of arbitrary size?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is a silly example but there's a few things you can do:

1. Know what happens when you call a Delphi function
2. Know your data
3. Move stuff outside the loop
4. Don't jump unless its predictable

Let me elaborate

**Know what happens when you call a Delphi function**
When you call an RTL function, like `string:= string + someotherstring`
Delphi will perform a `concat` operation. This involves resizing the string allocation (if needed) and moving the string (if needed) to a new location in memory.
If you do this many times all of the storage allocation will start to add up. In fact it you double the function to 20,000,000 runs you'll find that the runtime more than doubles.
So you avoid this nonsense and move those costly functions out of the loop.

**Know your data**
As soon as `s[index] = 0`, any multiplication will be 0. You can use this knowledge to speeds things up **a lot**. Some people call this cheating; in this case that may be true, but in a more complex case knowing what your data will do can get you very nice speeds ups.
Furthermore you know that multiplying a single digit times nine can never yield a result > 81 so you need not check more than 2 chars.

**Move stuff out of the loop**
Once you know your data you can move stuff out of the loop, so instead of doing them many times, you only do them once.
Even if the stuff outside the loop takes 10,000 times longer than the stuff inside the loop. It's still a good deal.

**Don't jump unless its predictable**
In this case this doesn't apply because the function will quickly stabilize on outputting a steady stream of zeros, but I put it in for demonstration purposes anyway.
In fact an `if` here will be faster than no `if` because the jump breaks a dependency chain.

Code example

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject); 
const
  NumberOfCharsForKToSettleTo0 = 10;
  ManyTimes = 10 * 1000 * 1000 
var
  i,j,k,l:integer;
  s:string;
begin
  //preallocate the length of the string
  SetLength(s, 4 + (ManyTimes * length('|1')) + NumberOfCharsForKToSettleTo0);
  s:='1369';
  l:= 4;
  for i:=1 to ManyTimes do begin
    j:=i mod 9;
    //k:=strtoint(s[Length(s)])*j; don't use strtoint
    k:= ord(s[l]) - ord('0');
    k:= k*j;
    //s:=s+'|'+inttostr(k);
    inc(l);
    s[l]:= '|';
    inc(l);
    s[l]:= chr(k div 10+ord('0'));
    inc(l,integer(k>9));  //avoid jumps/ifs that are hard to predict.
    s[l]:= chr(k+ord('0'));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Johan and Mason Wheeler. Can you help me for my real codes?If u can ı will share below. This codes is part of my codes.

Comment: @Johan The string can be evaluated at compile time

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I know. That's what I said when noting that it will quickly stabilize into a long line of zeros (separated by `|`).